# Movement animation with RealmRecyclerViewAdapter with Drag&Drop

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, realm

I have a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter that listens to a query in realm, and I've Implemented a drag and drop functionality on it using the ItemTouchHelper.

```
private final ItemTouchHelper.Callback _ithCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

    private int fromPosition;
    private int toPosition;

    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
            return false;
        }

        toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());

        return true;
    }

    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    }

    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == TaskListRecyclerViewAdapter.FOOTER) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return makeMovementFlags(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);

        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG) {
            fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            toPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        } else if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE
                && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            // adapter.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
            dragAndDropManager.executeDragAndDrop(liveRealm, store.getStoreUid(), fromPosition, toPosition);
            ...
            ...
            // adapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
        }
    }
};
```

To indicate the movement, whenever I drag an item over another Item, I call the adapter's notifyItemMoved method:

```
adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
```

and whenever the user releases the item he dragged, I commit the changes to the realm DB:

```
dragAndDropManager.executeDragAndDrop(liveRealm, store.getStoreUid(), fromPosition, toPosition);
```

the problem is - whenever I release the item I've dragged, the animation appears to be working as if I haven't dropped the item in its location, but as if the item starts moving from its original location to the location in which I've dropped it.

I understand that this happens because I've committed the changes to Realm and as such the change is notified in the adapter, but the animation looks buggy.

I've tried calling

```
adapter.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

and

```
adapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

to remove and add the listener to the adapter but it seems to be unreliable.

Is there a better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Michael - did you ever get this working to your satisfaction?

I just ran across your post, having the same issue. I'm using the local Java DB version of Realm and after reviewing several examples that show similar techniques for implementing drag and drop with the stock recyclerView (generally they are all using an array of strings as the data model, NOT something like a live DB such as Realm) here is my experience - what I saw as issues with the "standard" techniques and how I resolved them:

**Issues To Resolve**

*Issue 1: Custom Callback class forwards large numbers of onMove events*

The various examples I found (like this one [here](https://therubberduckdev.wordpress.com/2017/10/24/android-recyclerview-drag-and-drop-and-swipe-to-dismiss/)) always utilize a
    custom class that extends `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`. This classes typically defines
    an interface that is in turn implemented by the adapter. Then this class overrides
    onMove()/onSwiped from the Callback to call the `onViewMoved()/onViewSwiped()` method of the interface implemented by the adapter:

```
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    contract.onViewMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}
```

In the `onViewMoved()` implementation that is in the adapter, the examples typically update the data source, then call `notifyItemMoved()`:

```
public void onViewMoved(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
    User targetUser = usersList.get(oldPosition);
    User user = new User(targetUser);
    usersList.remove(oldPosition);
    usersList.add(newPosition, user);
    notifyItemMoved(oldPosition, newPosition);
}
```

In the example above, the data model is a simple ArrayList of "User" objects.

The problem I found with this when using Realm is that in the Callback `onMove()` gets called *a lot* as the user drags, which
    given what is happening in the standard interface implementation would cause a huge amount of DB
    writes.

*Issue 2: The drag animation stops as soon as a single row change is detected*

I noticed that as I was dragging the top row of the recyclerview down, as soon as it reached the very next row the animation stopped. Why? It is because as you found out the base class RealmRecyclerViewAdapter automatically updates itself when it gets notifications that the data model has changed, and this update apparently triggers the ItemTouchHelper to stop the animation.

To solve these two issues, I did the following:

Like the examples I found, I extended ItemTouchHelper.Callback into my own class. I utilize some variables to keep track of whether I have dragged over a new target or not:

```
public class RecyclerViewSwipeAndDragHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private SwipeAndDraggable implementor;
    private static final int POSITION_UNKNOWN = -1;
    private int oldPosition = POSITION_UNKNOWN;
    private int newPosition = POSITION_UNKNOWN;
```

And similar to the example, in this class I define the interface that will be used by my adapter:

```
public interface SwipeAndDraggable {
    void onViewMoved(int oldPosition, int newPosition);
    void onViewSwiped(int position);
    void onClearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
}
```

I added the onClearView() method in this interface to what is typically shown in the examples, more on how that is used in a moment.

To solve the first issue, I needed to consolidate all the `onMove()` callbacks into only a single call into my adapter. Fortunately, ItemTouchHelper already does a lot of this work for us. A return value of TRUE from `onMove()` will trigger a follow-up call to `onMoved()`. Returning FALSE does not. So, in my `Callback` implementation when I override `onMove()`, I don't call the implementer of the interface. Instead, I only keep track of whether or not I've dragged over the same target position, so that it only returns TRUE the first time I hit a new target (and I also noticed through testing the sometimes I would get an initial -1 value for `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`, so I test for that as well):

```
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    oldPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    if ( oldPosition > POSITION_UNKNOWN) {
        if ( newPosition != target.getAdapterPosition() ) {
            newPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Only when `onMove()` returns TRUE is `onMoved()` in the Callback subsequently called. It is in that method that I call my implementation of onViewMoved():

```
@Override
public void onMoved(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int fromPos, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target, int toPos, int x, int y) {
    super.onMoved(recyclerView, viewHolder, fromPos, target, toPos, x, y);
    implementor.onViewMoved(fromPos, toPos);
}
```

That is how I solved the first issue of needing to consolidate all the `onMove()` callbacks into a single update. I only get a call a single time now as the user drags over individual viewholders.

As to the second issue - like you I have disabled the data listening in the RealmRecyclerView. I used the technique in the article to utilize an image in my viewholder to instigate the drag (in my case, it is a thumbnail image representing the individual entry in the recyclerview). This is done as the last step in the onBindViewHolder() method:

```
        holder.getMediaImageView().setOnTouchListener((View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
            if (motionEvent.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Turn off the data change listener within the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter superclass, so that
                // when we make changes via the drag it doesn't automatically update - we will handle that manually
                onDetachedFromRecyclerView(mMediaRecyclerView);
                mItemTouchHelper.startDrag(holder);
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Now when my onViewMoved() method is called, I can adjust the data model manually and notify the adapter:

```
    public void onViewMoved(int oldPosition, int newPosition) {
        Timber.d("Recognized a movement to a new position: old position, new position is: %d, %d", oldPosition, newPosition);
        MediaDataMgr.get().moveMediaInPlaylist(oldPosition, newPosition, mPlaylist.getId());
        // RealmRecyclerViewAdapter is no longer automatically notified when underlying data changes, so need to make notify()* calls here
        notifyItemMoved(oldPosition, newPosition);
    }
```

MediaDataManager is a class I wrote that consolidates all my Realm access. Here is that method as an example of how I do this (as well as the technique of insuring I'm calling Realm from the same thread I am currently on):

```
public void moveMediaInPlaylist(int from, int to, String playlistId) {
    boolean success = false;
    boolean mainThread = Thread.currentThread().equals(Looper.getMainLooper().getThread());
    Realm realm = null;
    if (mainThread) {
        realm = mUIThreadRealm;
    } else {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }
    try {
        Playlist p = getPlaylist(playlistId);
        if ( p== null) {
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving playlist with ID: "+ playlistId );
        }
        realm.beginTransaction();
        p.getMediaList().move(from, to);
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d( "Exception deleting a Media in Playlist: %s", e.getMessage());
        success = false;
    } finally {
        if ( success ) {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        } else {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
        if (!mainThread) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then when clearView() is called in the Callback, I forward this to the adapter via the interface definition. In Callback:

```
public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    oldPosition = POSITION_UNKNOWN;
    newPosition = POSITION_UNKNOWN;
    implementor.onClearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
}
```

And in adapter implementation of the interface I use this to re-attach the data listener:

```
    public void onClearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        // reset RealmRecyclerViewAdapter data listener
        onAttachedToRecyclerView(mMediaRecyclerView);
    }
```

Now I am able to get a smooth looking animation, updating the DB in real time only once as items are dragged down the recyclerview using Realm:

[image]

Comment: I've managed to get it working by not using the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter's listener. The problem was as such:
User drags an item via the UI and changes the order of the items (items in the DB stay the same) -> in order to sync the order of the items in the UI with the order in the DB, we perform a realm transaction (UI and DB are synched)-> realm pops up a notification -> the adapter is notified and performs the change of items in the UI again -> the items change again and the user is confused.
no listener -> no synch issues (despite that removing the need for the base class altogether).

Comment: That might be a weird fix but now it works perfectly. There should be a solution via Realm itself somehow, but I don't see that happening anytime soon